# What situation might cause a camera Lens to lose its Image stabilization ability?

Tags: image-stabilization

Are there such situation(s) that can cause a camera (can be a point and shoot camera or a DSLR Lens) Lens to lose its image stabilization ability?

Comment: For *why* IS may appear to not be working you may also want to look at: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6039/why-is-image-stabilisation-making-images-unsharp?rq=1 and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8803/should-i-keep-image-stabilization-is-off-when-i-do-not-actually-need-it

Comment: @Miljenko -- rather than commenting (which adds noise) you can edit the post to correct obvious typos.

Comment: Is this theorectical, or are you trying to troubleshoot a problem?

Comment: @mattdm: I recon this to be more polite. But noise-wise, you are right, and I'll do that in the future.

Comment: @Miljenko -- on this site, just fixing simple problems is _more_ polite. It's different from a typical forum, in that the goal is to collaboratively create the best possible questions and answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about lenses permanently losing their stabilisation ability this could be due to any of the following factors

- failure of the switch which activates IS
- faults of the motion detection sensors
- failure of the control system
- failure of the IS motors
- jamming of the IS lens elements

which in turn may be the results of

- manufacturing defects
- physical shocks to the lens
- moisture or water damage

Answer (score 3):

I'm no lens doctor, but a good ol' drop on the floor might do it.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the optical IS function that is built into lenses is micro-gyro based, not image movement based, and so may be affected by a strong magnetic field.

Also, dirty contacts can cause all sorts of errors.